# how to remove download button in Facebook post?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-share

I have share my URL using Facebook share button.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

I have follow this link  for Facebook video share in my Facebook app

[image]

Comment: the content is generated by facebook, not a lot you can do about it. Anyway even if you removed the button, clever users can still find a way to download it. If you don't want people to download your stuff, the simple answer is don't share it on the internet.

Comment: This can be done in Youtube video is getting played and it's not downloadable. I have also tried the same way as Youtube  but video is not playing.

Comment: i don't want to restrict anyone from downloading my stuff I just want remove download button

Comment: why then? If you don't care if they download or not, why go to the effort to remove the button?

Comment: It's my requirement i don't want to show download button or controls

Comment: ok. I'm not convinced you easily can, since you're not in control of the markup. Unless you override the CSS or something to try and hide it, but then facebook might change it in future - they change their site design quite often. Still seems like a waste of time IMO, but it's up to you. That's my suggestion for how to try and do it, but I think it will be brittle.